# New variable based in non exact number of categoricals values in a tidydata format

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Trying to create a new variable based in several categorical conditions in a tidydata. This is an example of my data:

```r
d <- data.frame(
  x = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
  y = c("fruit", "fruit", "vegetables", "fruit", "vegetables", "vegetables", "vegetables")
)

d
#>   x          y
#> 1 a      fruit
#> 2 a      fruit
#> 3 b vegetables
#> 4 b      fruit
#> 5 b vegetables
#> 6 c vegetables
#> 7 c vegetables
```

The conditions to create the dataset are:

- If the same user has `fruit` in all the rows gets `fruit`
- If the same user has `vegetables` in all the rows gets `vegetables`
- If the same user has `vegetables` and/or `fruit` gets `mix`

So, the desired output looks like this:

```r
#>   x          y
#> 1 a      fruit
#> 2 b        mix
#> 3 c vegetables
```

So far I've tried to apply a custom function but since there is no exact number of rows for each user in `x` column I can't figure out a properly solution. It would be nice to use a **tidyverse solution**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
      group_by(x) %>%
      #Check if number of distinct "unique" for y within x==1, then get the first element of y else return 'mix' 
      summarise(y = ifelse(n_distinct(y) == 1, first(y), 'mix')) 

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x     y         
<chr> <chr>     
1 a     fruit     
2 b     mix       
3 c     vegetables
```

Answer (score 1):

Roll a function that compares the values to the factor levels, then aggregate.

```
f <- function(x) {
    if(all(levels(x) %in% x)) "mix" else unique(levels(x)[x])
}

aggregate(y ~ x, d, f)
#   x          y
# 1 a      fruit
# 2 b        mix
# 3 c vegetables
```

Answer (score 0):

### base r using `tapply`

```
tapply(d$y, d$x, function(x) if(length(u<-unique(x))==1) u else "mix")
#       a            b            c 
# "fruit"        "mix" "vegetables"
```

Or, if the formatting of the result matters:

```
res <- tapply(d$y, d$x, function(x) if(length(u<-unique(x))==1) u else "mix")
data.frame(x=names(res), y=res)
#   x          y
# a a      fruit
# b b        mix
# c c vegetables
```

Comment: you are looking for `aggregate(y~x,d,function(x)if(length(unique(x))>1)"mix" else x[1]) `